# Why the TCP traceroute map jump over many routers?

Tags: networking, traceroute

I can not understand this TCP traceroute map:

This is a TCP traceroute from Chongqing,China to LA,USA:

[image]

the `219.158.3.146` is Beijing Unicom the `219.158.96.26` is LA Unicom.

the path is this:

[image]

Why the Beijing next-hop arrive the LA?

the bellow snapshots shows the cities, and the submarine optical cable map, if network from China to USA, must go through the submarine optical cable, but why there directly from Beijing,China to LA,USA?

surely it doesn't mean that at least go through the Shanghai or Qingdao, or Guangdong?

[image]

[image]

---

Is it pass through satellite network? I don't think so.

Comment: Sadly, questions about networks you don't control are off topic here.  Unless you work for Beijing Telecom, any answer is just guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since its the same company and the same AS number its possible that packet don't passed any device that performing routing for that.

I can imagine that backbone in Beijing doing routing decisions then router 219.158.3.146 have direct cable without any layer 3 devices on the path to submarine cable and just crossing the whole ocean

Comment: Do you mean the `219.158.3.146 ` connect to the `219.158.96.26` with a long cable and no Layer2 routers between them?

Comment: there is no such thing like layer 2 routers, routers routing packets so they are by definition layer 3 devices. On the route to ocean it could pass some devices but this could be layer 1/2 devices that they just forward traffic to submarine cable